# Почему не срабатывает find

Tags: jquery, dom

При работе с SVG столкнулся с проблемой: не находится элемент `tspan` в строке.

Например, этот код не выведет ничего. В чём проблема?

```js
var subrows = "<tspan x='100' y='26.4'>​​ТЕст</tspan><tspan x='100' y='52.8'>И</tspan><tspan x='100' y='79.2'>Тест</tspan><tspan x='100' y='105.6'></tspan>";

$(subrows).find('tspan').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("y"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` ищет только среди потомков. Так как в `$(subrows)` находятся только 4 `<tspan>` на верхнем уровне, и у каждого из которых нет потомков, то `find` среди отсутствующих потомков ничего найти и не сможет.

Для поиска среди потомков и самих элементов можно воспользоваться комбинацией из методов `find` и `addBack`:

```js
var subrows = "<tspan x='100' y='26.4'>ТЕст<tspan y='internal_tspan_y'></tspan></tspan><tspan x='100' y='52.8'>И</tspan><tspan x='100' y='79.2'>Тест</tspan><tspan x='100' y='105.6'></tspan><p y='not_tspan_y'</p>";

$(subrows).find('tspan').addBack('tspan').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("y"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Внутренний `<tspan>` и `<p>` в конце добавлены для демонстрации корректности результата.

---

Если потомки вообще не предполагаются, и нужно просто отфильтровать `<tspan>` элементы, то достаточно воспользоваться методом `filter`:

```js
var subrows = "<tspan x='100' y='26.4'>ТЕст<</tspan><tspan x='100' y='52.8'>И</tspan><tspan x='100' y='79.2'>Тест</tspan><tspan x='100' y='105.6'></tspan><p y='not_tspan_y'</p>";

$(subrows).filter('tspan').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("y"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `$().find` ищет среди подэлементов элементов в выборке

https://api.jquery.com/find/